# How to make a patch of fabric js that convert all floating point value to rounded value?

Tags: fabricjs, patch

I am working in one project, in which I used fabricJS-3.6.3. It is a best library 
for canvas manipulations.

As we know the limitation of the canvas, canvas renders a half-pixel of an image. So sometimes it's blurry. Same Problem I put in front of you.

I am trying to render Text into canvas using following code

```
var text = new fabric.Textbox("lorem ipsum pixel", {
    top: 13.5
    left: 12.13
    width: 157.68
    fontSize: 15
    fontFamily: 'opensans-lightItalic'
    scaleX: 0.67
    scaleY: 0.67
})
canvas.add(text);
```

I have tried this code to make it round:

```
var text = new fabric.Textbox("lorem ipsum pixel", {
        top: 13.5
        left: 12.13
        width: 157.68
        fontSize: 15
        fontFamily: 'opensans-lightItalic'
        scaleX: 0.67
        scaleY: 0.67
    })
text.set({
   height: Math.round(text.height),
   width: Math.round(text.width)
})

canvas.add(text);
canvas.loadFromJSON(canvas.toJSON(), canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
```

Now the result of this code will always blurry Because canvas render `Half a Pixel` and we got image blurry.

So For clear Result, I have to just set it to with `Rounded value`. Now the actual problem is that project is too large and has a complex structure, So I want to make one `fabricJs patch` that automatically replace (top, left, scale ETC...) properties into rounded value. I have tried to make it using `fabric.Object` method override, but can't be got success in that.

If Anyone knows that how to access and set a property to all object, Then Please help me.

Comment: i have added my answer . for more help please add your screenshot

Comment: if you want a header kind of test i can help you.background ,fill, stroke, everything i have used ..for more brief please add a screenshot and clarify me what exactly you want

Comment: Text edge render in half pixel will cause text blur issue. So I want to set it to decimal point after render, so text will get clear to see in canvas. I want that set text height and width set in decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Textbox` you should use `IText`

```
var text = new fabric.IText('lorem ipsum pixel', {
    top: 13.5,
    left: 12.13,
    fontSize: 15,
    fontFamily: 'opensans-lightItalic'
});
canvas.add(text);
```

Comment: Thank For reply. I have tried it but need to make some changes.

Comment: do you need any other help. you can ask me

Comment: loadfromjson() function is automatically convert  itext height and width in floating point value. How Can I set it after load from json function call complete ? 

I was try to make it in loadfromjson's callback function , but can't set width and height of each i-text there !!

Comment: Could you please update your latest code so that i can help you

Comment: only thing i want to suggest you is don't use width and height in text otherwise the text will stretch

Comment: Height and width , top and left are just set with math.round() function so that text is not getting render in half pixel, actually I am not using width and height for text.